# Does a random sequence whose expectation is monotonically decreasing have a bounded sequence for its variance?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, expected-value

Let $(X_k)$ be a random sequence such that $(\Bbb{E}_{X_k}[X_k])$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence, i.e., $\Bbb{E}_{X_{k+1}}[X_{k+1}] \leq \Bbb{E}_{X_k}[X_k]$ for all $k$. Also, assume that $(\Bbb{E}_{X_k}[X_k])$ is bounded below.

Does $(Var(X_k))$ a bounded sequence?

**My thoughts:**

Intuitively, I feel the claim is true but when I write a single element of the sequence as the following, I do not know how to manage it.
$$Var(X_k)=\Bbb{E}_{X_k}[(X_k-\Bbb{E}_{X_k}[X_k])^2]=\Bbb{E}_{X_k}[(X_k)^2]-(\Bbb{E}_{X_k}[X_k])^2$$

Comment: Your notations are confusing. Do you mean sequence $(X_k)$ ?

Comment: @Dan: Yest. I will fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a counter example:

Let
$$ X_k = \begin{cases}
k & p\\
-k & 1-p,
\end{cases}
$$
with the probability $0< p < \frac12$.

Then $E[X_k] = k\,(2p-1)$ which is monotonically decreasing but the variance
is not bounded:

$$Var(X_k) = k^2 - k^2(2p-1)^2 = k^2(1-(2p-1)^2) \to \infty.$$

**Edit: (since you added a new condition on the sequence):**

Even if the sequence $E[X_k]$ is bounded below, the variance may not be bounded:

Let
$$ X_k = \begin{cases}
k & \frac13\\
-k & \frac13\\
\frac1k & \frac13
\end{cases}
$$
Then $E[X_k] = \frac{1}{3\,k}$ which is decreasing converging to $0$ but $E[X_k^2] = \frac23 k^2 + \frac{1}{3k^2} \rightarrow \infty$ and so the variance is unbounded.

Comment: I corrected the statement of the question. I meant a sequence not powers. Also, I added another condition on the expectation of the sequence which is boundedness from below.

Comment: your solution is not valid since the sequence of the expected value is not bounded below.

Comment: Because you added a new condition on the sequence!. I have edited the solution. Again, the variance may not be bounded.

Comment: Can you help me with my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4496112/608029)?